# Python replace list elements in 2 lists, at indexes of substrings in 3rd list

Tags: python, list, indexing, replace, slice

I have the following 3 Python lists:

```
cl_ambient = ['BRy', 'WilmB', 'Hgan', 'FoVx', 'Afree', 'FoVx_d', 'Afree_d']
temp_farh = ['grey', 'DarkOrange', 'r', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
manual_calib = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'darkgreen']
```

All 3 lists will always have the same length.

**Start with the list `cl_ambient`:**

I need to find the indexes of the elements in `cl_ambient` which is a substring of another element. In this case,
the indexes of such elements are at indexes 3,5 (Fovx,Fovx_d) and 4,6 (Afree,Afree_d).

**Now, once these indexes are found, I need to use these indexes to make replacement in both of the other 2 lists:**

I need to replace the higher index element from the other 2 lists (`temp_farh` and `manual_calib`) with the lower index element
from the `manual_calib` list. So, if we do this manually, the replacements should be:

```
temp_farh[5] = temp_farh[3]
temp_farh[6] = temp_farh[4]

manual_calib[5] = temp_farh[3]
manual_calib[6] = temp_farh[4]
```

I need to make these replacements programmatically. I cannot do this manually since the lists are likely to be quite long.

**Required Output:**

The output should be:

```
cl_ambient = ['BRy', 'WilmB', 'Hgan', 'FoVx', 'Afree', 'FoVx_d', 'Afree_d']
temp_farh = ['grey', 'DarkOrange', 'r', 'black', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow']
manual_calib = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow']
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to extract these substring elements programmatically from these 3 lists?

**Additional Information:**

1. As per the comment below, I will add this: there will not be a scenario where more than 2 substrings exists in the `cl_ambient` list. Example: `FoVx`, `FoVx_d`, `FoVx_a` will not exist. There will only be `Fovx_d` OR `Fovx_a`.
2. The substring will always be before the longer element in the `cl_ambient` list.

Comment: What if there is more than 2 substrings in `cl_ambient`. Example: `FoVx` `FoVx_d` `FoVx_a` then what will happen ?

Comment: Thanks for the note. This scenario will not be possible in the `cl_ambient` list. I will add this to the OP, Great question.

Comment: Is the substring always before the longer element?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I should have mentioned this in the OP. Yes! The substring will always be before the longer element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is splitted into two parts, first find the desired indexes we want to replace and then make the replace

the code:

```
cl_ambient = ['BRy', 'WilmB', 'Hgan', 'FoVx', 'Afree', 'FoVx_d', 'Afree_d']
temp_farh = ['grey', 'DarkOrange', 'r', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
manual_calib = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'darkgreen']


# for each index search match on the higher indexes, 
# if found save it on the changes list as (high, low) tuple
changes = [(i+1+j, i) for i, s1 in enumerate(cl_ambient)
           for j, s2 in enumerate(cl_ambient[i+1:]) 
           if (s1 in s2 or s2 in s1)]
print(changes)

# do the change on both lists
for i, j in changes:
    temp_farh[i] = manual_calib[j]
    manual_calib[i] = manual_calib[j]

print(temp_farh)
print(manual_calib)
```

output:

```
[(5, 3), (6, 4)]
['grey', 'DarkOrange', 'r', 'black', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow']
['white', 'white', 'white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow']
```

Comment: Thanks. Your `manual_calib` works great. However, for `temp_farh` list, I need the last 2 elements to be `blue`,'yellow'.

Comment: Oh wait. Sorry it works if you just make one change. Change the first line inside your `for` loop to this: `temp_farh[i] = manual_calib[j]`